# Link to most recent child page

Tags: permalinks, child-pages

in the header of a website I am trying to link to the most recent child page of a particular parent page. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this.
Does anyone have any input on this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! This is what I did:

```
<?php query_posts(array('orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_parent' => $page_id, 'post_type' => 'page')); while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Link</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_query() ?>
```

It makes a loop of sub-pages to a particular page and limits it to only 1 page. Nice and easy :)

Hope this can be of any help to someone else.